# Numberformat seems to ignore decimal places in Android - but only for US-Dollar and only in Germany

Tags: java, android, string, number-formatting

I'm having a really strange bug, where NumberFormat seemingly ignores the fraction digits I set. 
I'm using this rather simple method to format a double value representing a currency into a locale-specific String to show on screen:

```
public static String formatValueString(String currencyISO, double value) {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    if (value != Math.floor(value)) {
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    } else {
        numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    }
    numberFormat.setCurrency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(currencyISO));
    String result = numberFormat.format(value);
    return result;
}
```

It should show 2 decimal places only when needed, which according to the documentation of setCurrency should work:

> Sets the currency used by this number format when formatting currency values. **The min and max fraction digits remain the same.**

Well.. It works most of the time. 2.0 with ISO "GBP" is correctly formated to "2 £" when the device language is set to German and "£2" when it's set to English in the US.

However 2.0 with "USD" as ISO results in "2,00 $", when set to German. All other languages and all other currencies I have tested work as intended.

I really have no idea, what I could be doing wrong for it to only not work in that one specific case. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I tried this simplified version:

```
public static String formatValueString(String currencyISO, double value) {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    numberFormat.setCurrency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(currencyISO));
    String result = numberFormat.format(value);
    return result;
}
```

Same result, still shows 2 decimal places that shouldn't be there(again, only for US-Dollar in German), the Math.floor part is definitely not the problem.

**Edit 2:**
Doing this with screenshots now. Ignore all the commented and other unimportant stuff.

[image]
With "EUR" and 2.0 as value everything works fine and the result is "2 €"

[image]
But with "USD" and the same value the result is now "2.00 $".

In both cases the maximumFractionDigits and minimumFractionDigits are still correctly set to 0 in the numberFormat object, after the setCurrency().

**So where are these decimal places coming from???**

Comment: Then you didn't test Dutch as that would be the same as for German. Two dollar writes as 2,00 $. Concerning numbers and currency , and . are interchanged compared to USA. So the `DecimalSeparator`is different here.

Comment: Agreed, this works as expected.

Comment: @greenapps I think you misunderstood my problem. I'm German myself, so I know about using , instead of . . My Problem is that it shows 2 decimal places, which it shouldn't, as obviously 2.0 == Math.floor(2.0). And yes, I did test Dutch, it shows up as an integer, without the ",00", as expected.

Comment: You are sure that floor() does not make a mistake? Isn't floor() the problem?

Comment: @greenapps Tried it without, same result. See my edit.

Comment: Please show with wich values you call this function.

Comment: Tested this and I'm getting "$2".

Comment: @greenapps I edited with screenshots. I hope my problem becomes clear now.

Comment: @matiash Are you sure, you have language set to German? It _should_ be "2 $" (with currency symbol after the number and a space in between) if everything worked correctly. Anyway, I added screenshots of my debug, please take a look.

Comment: Sorry, you're right... I hadn't set to German. :) Most strange, looks like a bug.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not simply use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)`?

Comment: @matiash Well, because I want locale dependent formatting. As a German, the € symbol before the amount looks rather strange and uncommon to me. But I guess it might be a bug.. Looks like I have to find another solution.

Comment: For Dutch its € 234,00 or nicer € 234,- or just € 234 clean. I believed you already but asked for statements which i could copy and paste to try out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same issue today and was able to work around it. Basically, when you set the currency on a NumberFormat, it overwrites the minimum and maximum fraction digits.  You can see it here in this copy of the JDK code: https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/util/locale/provider/NumberFormatProviderImpl.java#L212

Once you know this, it's pretty easy to workaround: you just set the currency before setting anything else.

```
public static String formatValueString(String currencyISO, double value) {
    NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    numberFormat.setCurrency(java.util.Currency.getInstance(currencyISO));
    numberFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    String result = numberFormat.format(value);
    return result;
}
```

That's it.  Now you should have the correct number of fractional digits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I never got around to updating this. The corresponding issue is here, actually suggesting the same workaround: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36997153

Comment: What if I want to format values for Bitcoin (BTC) or Ethereum (ETH)? These are not yet in ISO, so I can't call `setCurrency()`.